# Update UI on insertions to Database using RxJAVA and DAO

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have a `ChatThreadsActivity()` which displays messages between two people.

Whenever the user opens the activity, I make an API to fetch the most recent 100 messages. So in the `onCreate()` method I call `makeApiRequestToGetChatThread()`.

I know I am doing alot of things wrong here.

1. Inside `onNext()` I add rows to the `chatThreadAdapter`. I know this is wrong since I update adapter after ever insert.
2. `chatDaoObject.queryChatThreadsFromDB(someId).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe()`

   Should this be anonymously called? When will this be unsubscribed if ever?
3. How do I unsubscribe from it?
4. I've read about BackPressure and realize this is it, I've run this on Android Monitor and here's how I can identify it. Am I doing this right?

[image]

---

```
private void makeApiRequestToGetChatThreads() {
  public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) {
    final String responseString = response.body().string();
    runOnUiThread (() -> {
      final JSONArray array = new JSONArray(responseString);
      JSONObject obj;
      for (int i=0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
        obj = new JSONObject(array.get(i));
        insertAChatIntoDB (obj);
      }
    }
  });
}

private void insertAChatIntoDB(JSONObject o) {
  if(insertSubscriber != null) {
    insertSubscriber.unsubscribe();
  }

  insertSubscriber = new Subscriber<Long>() {
    public void onCompleted() {

    }
    public void onError() {

    }
    public void onNext() {
      chatDaoObject.queryChatThreadsFromDB(someId)
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(new Action1<List<ChatObject>>() {
        @Override
          public void call(List<ChatObject> chatList) {
            if (chatList != null) {
              //Royal Screw up
              //After every insertion in the DB I update the UI
              chatThreadAdapter.addAllChatThreadsIntoList(chatList);

              //Notify is called inside the above below
              //notifyItemRangeChanged(initialPosition,chatList.size()) 
            }
          }
      }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
          @Override
          public void call(Throwable throwable) {

          }
      });

    }
  };


  try {
    //Inserts happening on Schedulers.computation()
    chatDaoObject.insertAChatInDB(o).observeOn(Schedulers.computation()).subscribe(insertSub);
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Crashlytics.logException(e);
  }
}
```

I use RxJAVA and SQLBrite Dao and here's what the query looks like:

```
//In `ChatDao` class
ChatDataDao extends Dao {
  ...
  ...
  public Observable<long> insertAChatInDB(JSONObject o) {
    ChatThreadsTable.ContentValuesBuilder valuesBuilder = ChatThreadsTable.contentValues();
    ...
    //populating columns values
    ...
    return insert(ChatThreadsTable.TABLE_NAME, valuesBuilder.build(), SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
  }
  public Observable<List> queryChatThreadsFromDB () {
    return rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + ChatThreadsTable.TABLE_NAME).run().mapToList(ChatObjectMapper.MAPPER);
  }
  ...
  ...
}
```

Edit:

Is this the right way to query db without worrying about subscription/unsubscription?

```
rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SomeObject.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + SomeObject.COL1 + " , " +SomeObject.COL2 + " DESC").run().mapToList(SomeObjectMapper.MAPPER)
  .flatMap(new Func1<List<SomeObject>, Observable<SomeObject>>() {
      @Override
      public Observable<SomeObject> call(List<SomeObject> SomeObjects) {

          return Observable.from(SomeObjects);
      }
  }).doOnNext(new Action1<SomeObject>() {
      @Override
      public void call(SomeObject chatThreadObject) {
      }
  }).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

what is going on with all these tutorials telling people to create their own `Subscriber`s? Here's a cleaned up version:

```
private void makeApiRequestToGetChatThreads() {
  // ... some call that calls back onResponse
}
public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) {
  // are you sure this is how you parse a JSON String?
  Observable
    .from(response.body().string())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .flatMapIterable(JsonArray::new)
    .map(JSONObject::new)
    .flatMap(chatDaoObject::insertAChatInDB)
    .flatMap(chatDaoObject::queryChatThreadsFromDB)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnNext(chatThreadAdapter::addAllChatThreadsIntoList)
    .subscribe(dummy -> {}, throwable -> {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
    });
}
```

- It's quite likely that there's a better way to directly make the network call return an Observable. Check your documentation / peers.
- When the Observable completes all processing and UI updates, it will unsubscribe on it's own. However, if the network call takes a while to complete, the user might have already switched screens/apps, and the UI manipulation will break your app. Consider saving the subscription in your view and unsubscribing. Hint: creating the subscription in the `onResponse` is... not optimal.
- You are getting 100s of threads, and updating the UI for each and every one of them. Are you sure you want that?
- I don't think you need to care about backpressure.

Comment: We use SQLBrite Dao https://github.com/sockeqwe/sqlbrite-dao which maps the query result to an object and returns `Observable<List<ChatObject>>`. Since they are using `Observable.defer()` [definition: do not create the `Observable` until the observer subscribes, and create a fresh Observable for each observer]. So in order to achieve this, we have to create a subscription inside our activity which is anonymous. What's the best way to unsubscribe from that subscription?

Comment: You don't. See the code snippet above. The Dao gives you an Observable that emits a single item, then it calls `onComplete`. If you do a `flatMap`, it will take care of the subscription/item production/completion lifecycle.

Comment: I didn't understand what the `subscribe` does here. What's the `dummy` for? Second param is the error handler, but what's `dummy`?

Comment: A dummy argument - you don't need to do anything with the items, all the processing has been completed in the observable chain above, but for easy access to the error handler you need to provide a value, so we provide one that is a no-op.

Comment: Pls check the edit. Is that the right way to query DB?

Comment: I think that's a way to do DB calls, but my preferred dialect is to subscribe once, for the whole operation from start to finish (if you use retrofit, that can include multiple network calls); this also allows you to easily cancel the whole operation by unsubscribing. Also, embrace lambdas, the code is much easier to read. Finally, `.flatMapIterable(list->list)` is enough to replace your whole 1st flatMap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130776/discussion-between-slearner-and-tassos-bassoukos).